# How do you create double doors that open in sync from a 2-wide power source?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I've got a double door which I power from below, using a T-flip flop triggered by a pressure plate on the inside so that when I walk out, the doors open before me and when I walk in, the doors close behind me. It's a very good design for me, but, while powering the doors from below, I usually have to put one powered from off to the side instead of both from the inside. I found the design in my image, which is only 2 wide (I uncovered it, it would usually be covered), on this site, used for something else. However, the two doors are a half-step out of sync, i.e. with the repeaters in this position, one opens before the other, and if I delay the first one with one click on the repeater, the behavior is switched. In this configuration (the delays are equal), the left door always opens and closes a half-step earlier.

How can I get the doors perfectly in sync?

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually a very easy fix. Your design is something like this:

[image]

The extra delay comes from the raising of the signal on top of the block, which is actually unnecessary. Simply lower the signal, like so:

[image]

And there you have it. The doors will now be in sync.

Comment: I didn't know that would power them both.

Comment: Also, what texture pack is this? I basically don't pay attention to this stuff because I have a friend who maintains his own and lets me use it.

Comment: @Andrew OCD Texture Pack. I like to use it for redstone, but I find using it for gameplay a little jarring.